# C# EF Deep Lambda Distinct Count Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lambda

This is the query I am trying to do.

```
var commentActivity = project.ProjectDoc
        .Select(c => c.Comment.Select(i => i.UserID))
        .Distinct()
        .Count();
```

What I want is the number of comments from distinct users on a specific project, but ANY ProjectDoc. This query "works" the result is just wrong. The model is like this, generically sketched.

```
 Project
      ProjectDoc
           Comment
```

Update: I had to go one level deeper, based on the answer below I tried a few things that didn't work so I though I would post this as a reference. Note the two SelectMany methods.

```
 var replyActivity = project.ProjectDoc
      .SelectMany(c => c.Comment.SelectMany(r => r.CommentReply.Select(u => u.UserID)))
      .Distinct()
      .Count();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SelectMany instead of Select

```
project.ProjectDoc
        .SelectMany(c => c.Comment.Select(i => i.UserID))
        .Distinct()
        .Count()
```

Comment: After hours of fiddling I just came up with this same thing 2 minutes ago... not that it was on purpose, just a happy accident. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 var data =   (from con in project.ProjectDoc
               select new 
              {
                 CommentCount=project.Comment.Count(x=>x.UserID==con.UserID)

              }).ToList();
```

i think this will help you.